# Lightning component reload

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using the following to reload a page. It is reloading but,If a user is entering some data in a page and the page gets reloaded automatically and the data entered is not existing.
which means the user need to enter the whole data once again.

is there a Renderer method to reload with the data.

If so please help me out.

```
({
    unrender: function (cmp, helper) {
        this.superUnrender();
        window.location. (cmp.get("v.countdown"));
    }
})
```

Comment: why are we using buttons here ?

Answer (score 1):

> There is a better way to do this instead of using renderer. You can
>   leverage [`lightning:unsavedChanges`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) **starting from spring 19 release.(Currently you can test in spring 19 orgs!)**

This component provides a way to notify the UI containment hierarchy of unsaved changes and to participate in saving or discarding those changes based on the user's decision.To access the methods, create an instance of the lightning:unsavedChanges component inside of your component and assign an aura:id attribute to it.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
    <lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
                              onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                              ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}" />
    <lightning:button label="Make Unsaved Changes" onclick="{!c.makeUnsavedChanges}" />
    <lightning:button label="Clear Unsaved Changes" onclick="{!c.clearUnsavedChanges}" />
<aura:component>
```

The buttons invoke the makeUnsavedChanges and clearUnsavedChanges client-side controller methods. If the user takes some action that would lose unsaved content such as closing its console tab container then a dialog appears prompting them to save or discard it. The handleSave or handleDiscard method is called based on their selection. These methods are required to call the setUnsavedChanges() method to return control back to the Lightning UI, as demonstrated below.

```
({
     makeUnsavedChanges: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
         var unsaved = cmp.find("unsaved");
         unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true, { label: 'My component name' });
     },
     clearUnsavedChanges: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
         var unsaved = cmp.find("unsaved");
         unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(false);
     },
     handleSave: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
         ... my custom save logic
         // When the custom save logic has completed the setUnsavedChanges method
         // must be called again to return control to the lightning UI
         var unsaved = cmp.find("unsaved");
         if (something went wrong) {
           // return control to the lightning UI while indicating that the content is still unsaved, preventing it from being dismissed
           unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true);
         }
         else {
           // return control to the lightning UI while indicating that the content is saved
           unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(false);
         }
     },
     handleDiscard: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        // similar to the handleSave method, but for discarding changes
     }
})
```

Only change is that it gives an additional option for the end user weather to persist the data or not by providing the button to save or clear the data!

Comment: You should add, its available from Spring 19 and cant be deployed now in prods.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I overlooked, Thanks for the prompt!